# Prolog how to delete from a list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to delete an element form a list of lists. This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
List=[[1,2],[1,3],[4,2]]
Max=2
delete(List,[_|Max],List2)
List2=[[1,3]]
```

Explanation: so given `List` I'm trying to use delete/3 to remove every element that has `Max` as its second element in its sub list. I'm not sure if this is possible with the standard delete/3 predicate. Thanks for the help!

This is what I have tried so far for my own predicate. I realize this isn't working and won't do what I want it.

```
second_element(E, []).
second_element(E,L):-
   member(X,L),
   X==[_,E],
   delete(L,X,L2),
   second_element(E,L2).
```

Comment: This is a simple exercise and doesn't require the `delete` predicate. If you read the documentation for `delete/3`, that's not how it works. Here's a free hint: `second_element(E, [_,E|_]).`. Then `second_element(X, L)` succeeds if and only if `X` is the second element of `L`. The rest is common recursive list traversal in Prolog. Try to show some work and then ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, could you elaborate on how the first predicate works? it doesnt seem like that would work for a list of lists.

Comment: `simple_element(E, [_,E|_]).` simply says that the second argument is a list whose second element is the same as the first argument. It's how Prolog works. it defines *relations*. What makes it work is the when Prolog sees `E` more than once in a single predicate clause, it unifies them (logically assumes they represent the same value). A slightly simpler predicate would be `head_of_list(Head, List)` which could simply be written as `head_of_list(H, [H|_]).`.

Comment: The hint of `second_element(E, [_,E|_])` just provides a rule for how to tell if an element of your original list should be kept. You still need to write the predicate (maybe called `lists_without_second_element/3`) that uses that rule. Such a predicate would be a simple recursive list processing predicate. You don't need `delete` or anything like that. It would need 3 arguments: The element you want to check, the original list, and the list that doesn't have the sublists with the second element indicated.

Comment: `second_element(E, []).` isn't a logical relation. It says that anything (`E`) is related to the empty list `[]` which is not meaningful.

Comment: Note that you can safely replace `X==[_,E]` by `false`. That is, it will always fail!

Comment: What about `[[1,2,3]]`? Is it filtered out or not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to just give you the answer to your assignment. But I can give you a pattern commonly used in Prolog that it follows. This plus the hint I provided in comments are all the tools you need to solve the problem.

If you have a list, `L`, and you want another list, `RL`, that omits those elements of `L` that meet a certain criteria, then this is handled with a common recursive pattern:

```
filtered_list([], []).     % The empty list is a filtered version of the empty list

filtered_list([H|T], R) :-
    (   meets_criteria_for_omission(H)
    ->  R = RT                 % R will not have H if it meets criteria for omission
    ;   R = [H|RT]             % R will have H if it does not meet criteria for omission
    ),
    filtered_list(T, RT).
```

In the case of the original problem, the criteria for omission is that the element being checked is a list whose second element is given. That means that element being checked against must be provided as an argument. And the criteria to check is whether it is the second element of the given list.

This is as much information as I can give without simply handing over the complete answer, but it's 85% of the way there. Time to use the noodle.

Comment: So what about `filtered_list([X], Xs)?`